# Cannot install h5py

Tags: python, pip, package, h5py

I'm trying to install [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/), but when I do `pip install h5py` or use `python setup.py install` from the source code, fatal error:

```
hdf5.h: No such file or directory.
```

Other posts mention to do `pip install libhdf5-dev` or `pip install libhdf5-serial-dev` to resolve this, but it says "no matching distribution found."

How can I install h5py? I am ssh'd into an Odyssey computer using the CentOS 6.5 version of the Linux. Also, I do not have sudo privileges. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! As it stands the question is rather hard to answer.  You need to put some more information in there - for example which operating system you're using.  You might find the [official installation instructions](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html#install) helpful.  You might want to look at how to write a [minimal, complete and verifiable example]{http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help make this question answerable.  Good luck!

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thank you for your suggestion!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link helped:
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/23144

I installed LinuxHomeBrew and did:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install hdf5
pip install h5py
```

I was able to install h5py!

Comment: tap homebrew/science is deprecated fyi

Answer (score 4):

Your error is because you are missing the `hdf5.h` header, *pip* will not install the development headers, you need to install them using your package manager,  on *Centos* it would be:

```
yum install hdf5-devel
```

If you look at the installation instrcutions:

[Source installation on Linux and OS X](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html#source-installation-on-linux-and-os-x)

*You need, via apt-get, yum or Homebrew:*

*Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 with development headers (python-dev or similar)*

*HDF5 1.8.4 or newer, shared library version with development headers (libhdf5-dev or similar)*

*NumPy 1.6.1 or later*

Comment: I don't have sudo privileges, is there any other command to install it? I am ssh'd into a virtual machine.

Comment: I used LinuxHomeBrew and did: brew tap homebrew/science, then brew install hdf5, and then pip install h5py which worked! Thank you!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771752/python-importerror-undefined-symbol-intel-sse2-str-chr

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-h5py
```

([Source](https://www.howtoinstall.co/es/ubuntu/xenial/python-h5py))

Comment: This is simplest and quicked way to install h5py in Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

Also, not `pip install libhdf5-dev` or `pip install libhdf5-serial-dev`, but `apt install libhdf5-dev` and `apt install libhdf5-serial-dev`.
Then, run `pip install h5py`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final solution of installing h5py successfully in python 3.6 and Jetson Nano. I have tried multiple answers from the community but nothing work. Actually the problem was in Cython version compatibility.
Do as following in step by step, my issue was resolved in 2nd steps, if your still doesn't work then go for the 3 option.

```
 0. pip install setuptools==59.6.0
 1. pip install Cython==0.29.16
 2. pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py==2.10.0
 3. install fenics-calc by python setup.py install
```

Almost 2nd option will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Running the below fixed my problem as I had an error related to `xlocale.h`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
```