# can't install h5py (error failed building wheel for h5py)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, h5py

I m trying to install h5py on raspberry pi using

```
pip install h5py
```

and the installation always failed with

```
error:failed building wheel for h5py
```

Comment: Please include the full output of pip in your question

Comment: You are familiar that python 2 is not supported any more, right?

Comment: yeah , i think so i did intall it and now and use it with python 2 and now I have a problem which is IOerror I think it is related to h5py , do you have an idea about it ,I really need help

Comment: I already told you that you need to include complete information, else nobody is able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try
`sudo -H pip3 install h5py`
It works for me.

Comment: Here is the solution, you can find it. I have given a detail solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321662/14578749

Answer (score 0):

please try `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

Comment: Not only this does not answer the question, it assumes that OP uses Linux, although they can be using Windows.

Comment: yes but for windows??