# Unable to install h5py on windows using pip

Tags: python-3.x, keras, h5py

I am using python version 3.8.5 and I have pip version 20.2.4 on Windows 10 64-bit.
I need to install the h5py to install Keras library for which I run the command `pip install h5py` in the cmd . This gives me the following error:

```
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.5; python_version == "3.8" in c:\python\python385\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.19.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python385\python.exe' 'c:\python\python385\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\kavya\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpclucl78r'
       cwd: C:\Users\kavya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xsxj61fv\h5py
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I get the same problem when I directly install keras using `pip install keras` as that also requires h5py. I am using pycharm and even installing keras from there is showing an error which I think is because of h5py

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this problem too when attempting to install keras, but this command helped me to install all dependencies needed for h5py (and keras):

```
pip install versioned-hdf5
```

After this I could also successfully install keras. **The command also downloads h5py as well.**

Comment: Here is the solution, you can find it. I have given a detail solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321662/14578749