# How to resolve the ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, h5py

I am working on windows 7.
Currently I have tensorflow 2.4.1 and keras 2.3.1 installed in my laptop.

I have trained a model on coalab and saved t on my laptop. When I try to load it it gives error :

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

It may be due to difference in version of Keras. Google colab uses Keras 2.4.3.

When I tried to install keras 2.4.3 using command:

```
pip install Keras==2.4.3
```

### *I got the following error:
Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.*

ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly*.

I tried to install h5py as well but it gives an error too!

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

while : h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly, try this

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

or check the python version , for example  h5py 2.6 only supports up to python 3.6 , look at [this](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/2.6.0/#files).

Comment: Here is the solution, you can find it. I have given a detail solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321662/14578749