# Error in installing tensorflow-macos and PyQt5 on PyCharm MacOs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, pyqt5, apple-m1

I was installing packages on PyCharm MacOs, and I had nearly installed everything. But every time I tried to install PyQt5 or tensorflow-macos, it'll fail.

For tensorflow-macos, it will report [see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16QPY.png). Then I tried to install "h5py", but it reports the same problem.

For PyQt5, every time it just says
[see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BBWJ.png)
, and I have tried everything on the internet, but nothing works.

What was I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930157/unable-to-install-pyqt5-on-raspberry-pi) for PyQT5 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017188/how-to-resolve-the-error-failed-building-wheel-for-h5py) for Tensorflow.

Comment: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/albert/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python3 /Users/albert/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/z3/360_cjx12wd6ktgqhl3gxmnw0000gn/T/tmpr4inlp4m Check the logs for full command output.
` came out when I tried to download PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz then use `pip install ./PyQt5-5.15.6. I don't know what's happening

Comment: Oh, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444207/how-to-fix-error-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-when-t) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58984045/16136190) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python." when trying to install django-heroku using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444207/how-to-fix-error-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-when-t)

Comment: I tried your method, but it reports `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5==5.15.6 (from versions: 5.14.0, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, 5.15.0, 5.15.1, 5.15.2, 5.15.3, 5.15.4, 5.15.5, 5.15.6)`, I mean, the version is in the list it gave!!!

Comment: :O That's weird... how could it show such an error, LOL? Did you try `python3 -m pip install <pkg>` or `python -m pip install <pkg>`?